# Tabu part of text in cell not visible

Tags: tables, tabu

I have problems with the tabu, when I make a table with the code below, the contents of the last column in the first row is not all visible. Why is this?

[image: Screenshot from the table]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Explanation }
\label{table:browsing_history}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to 1.0\textwidth{|c|c|c|c|X[m,c]|}
\hline
User & Contacts & Timestamp & Restaurant & Ranking of selected restaurant \\ \hline
1 & ~ &  13.6.2013.10.33.43  & Restaurang Upper East & 3    \\ \hline
1 & 2,3 & 13.6.2013.10.34.2  & World Class  & 2  \\ \hline
3 & 4 &  14.6.2013.11.10.19 & Secret Recipe &  10   \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `tabu` (many bugs and compatibilty issues with new versions, according to waht I've heard); use [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Explanation}
\label{table:browsing_history}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|C|}
\hline
User & Contacts & Timestamp & Restaurant & Ranking of selected restaurant \\ \hline
1 & ~ &  13.6.2013.10.33.43  & Restaurang Upper East & 3    \\ \hline
1 & 2,3 & 13.6.2013.10.34.2  & World Class  & 2  \\ \hline
3 & 4 &  14.6.2013.11.10.19 & Secret Recipe &  10   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice some extra space added with

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
```

(thanks to **David Carlisle** for this suggestion).

Perhaps you could be interested in the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to produce beautiful tables (no vertical lines allowed).

Here's your table with booktabs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Explanation }
\label{table:browsing_history}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccccC}
\toprule
User & Contacts & Timestamp & Restaurant & Ranking of selected restaurant \\ \midrule
1 & ~ &  13.6.2013.10.33.43  & Restaurang Upper East & 3    \\ 
1 & 2,3 & 13.6.2013.10.34.2  & World Class  & 2  \\ 
3 & 4 &  14.6.2013.11.10.19 & Secret Recipe &  10   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that instead of the `center` environment I used `\centering` to prevent additional vertical space.

Comment: +1 You beat me by a few seconds:-), mine was the same but I was going to suggest `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hehe! Good suggestion (using `\extrarowheight`). I've incorporated it into my answer.

Comment: The author said on c.t.t. that the new version he is currently working on will most likely break existing documents. Here's the enlightening thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI/bDD-jypImbQJ

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that not as a comment, but there is no possibility of adding pictures. Please give a MWE. In a clean `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\textwidth14cm
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Explanation }
\label{table:browsing_history}
\begin{center}
%\begin{tabu} to 1.0\textwidth{|c|c|c|c|X[m,c]|}
\begin{tabu} to 1.0\textwidth{|c|c|c|c|X[m,c]|}
\hline
User & Contacts & Timestamp & Restaurant & Ranking of selected restaurant \\ \hline
1 & ~ &  13.6.2013.10.33.43  & Restaurang Upper East & 3    \\ \hline
1 & 2,3 & 13.6.2013.10.34.2  & World Class  & 2  \\ \hline
3 & 4 &  14.6.2013.11.10.19 & Secret Recipe &  10   \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

so yours is rather side effect of mixing packages.